# Current flowing through a Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, dc

If we connect a pure DC voltage source with only a pure capacitor then what how the graph of current and voltage against time would look like? There would be a transient current and transient voltage across the capacitor I know but I do not understand what would be their shapes?

My book shows me the graph when a DC source is connected with a resistor and a capacitor in series and that graph is the exponential decay for the current and the exponential rise for the voltage across the capacitor.

But what if there is no resistance and the DC source is connected with pure capacitor? Then how will the current and voltage across the capacitor look like? Please someone show me their graphs against time.

Comment: Have you tried to simulate or calculate it?

Comment: Sneaky... a sim will fail if there isn't a series resistance, as the current will be infinite.

Comment: I tried but couldnt get anything.

Comment: If you connect an ideal voltage source across an ideal capacitor then the voltage across the capacitor will rise to be equal to that of the voltage source in zero time and an infinite current will flow. I also suspect that the Universe may be destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

The current will be an infinitesimally short spike of infinite magnitude (a Dirac delta function scaled to your capacitor's Q, if I'm remembering my signals and systems class correctly).  The voltage across the capacitor will instantaneously rise to your voltage source's level.  In the real world, there is no such thing as "perfect" voltage sources, wires, or capacitors, so you will have parasitic R, L, C, and also quite a bit of EM emission which will all bring things down to finite values.

Comment: Yup the current would instantly fall from a high value to zero and voltage from 0 to the source voltage but my question is how would they look like.

Comment: @Alex what does something infinitely tall and infinitely thin look like?

Comment: @Andy aka. What would and why would it be infinitely thin? I can understand it would be infinitely tall because the current would be infinite in the beginning. But what would be infinitely thin?

Comment: Because it takes zero time to charge.

Comment: So when we connect voltage source to a capacitor it would take zero time to charge and there would be infinite current in zero time?

Comment: @Alex More specifically, the current waveform would be a Dirac delta function. This, of course, wouldn't be the case in reality, only when using mathematically ideal circuit elements.

Comment: @Alex  NOTHING happens 'instantly'.  It's really fast maybe, but not instant.  Electric fields travel at the speed of light.  That's not infinite.  Only mathematicians and maybe astronomers accept infinity as an answer - The rest of us live in the real world.

Comment: @Kyle B. So if electric field is established across the capacitor with the speed of light then I guess the current across the capacitor would be slower than that. Right? What would be the graph of that current look like against time?

Comment: @Alex  I don't mean literally that the cap charges at the speed of light.  I was trying to demonstrate that there IS a limit to how fast electricity can move, and therefore the mathematical image of an infinitely tall spike with infinitesimally thin width is not possible in the real world.   As others have said many times here, wire inductance and resistance can't be avoided.   So EVERY graph of a charging capacitor is going to have the same SHAPE  (i.e. similar looking curves).  Some may be very very tall and thin, others very short and fat.  But all basically the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

The voltage-current relation in a capacitor in the time domain is given by the following formula:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)=\text{C}\cdot\frac{\partial\text{V}\left(t\right)}{\partial t}\tag1$$

So, when the voltage across the capacitor switches from \$0\space\text{V}\$ to some other voltage the \$\frac{\partial\text{V}\left(t\right)}{\partial t}\$ term will \$\to\infty\$.